# WrongTypeOfReturnValue: "Object" cannot be returned by findById()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I am trying to do tests for my Spring boot application, and I've got a big problem. This is how my error looks like:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
WorkItem cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

I was following tutorials and everyone is using `findOne()`, but for me it just doesn't work. My IDE shows:

> " Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.java.workitemservice.model.WorkItem"

That's why I tried it the other way and used `findById()`, but then I got another error.

```
{ 
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
    @SpringBootTest  
    public class WorkitemServiceApplicationTests {  

    @Mock  
    private WorkItemRepository workItemRepository;

    @InjectMocks
             WorkItemsController workItemsController;

    @Before
    public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUserById() {
    WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem();
    workItem.setId(1L);

    //old version
    //when(workItemRepository.findOne(1L)).thenReturn(workItem);
    when(workItemRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null)).thenReturn(workItem);

    WorkItem workItem2 = workItemsController.getWorkItemById(1L);

    verify(workItemRepository).findById(1L).orElse(null);

    assertEquals(1L, workItem2.getId().longValue());
    }
}
```

My Repository :

```
    @Repository
    public interface WorkItemRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkItem, 
    Long> {

    Optional <WorkItem> findWorkItemBySubject(String subject);
    }
```

My service method:

```
    public WorkItem getWorkItemById(Long id) {
    return this.workItemRepository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new 
    ResourceNotFoundException("WorkItem", "id", id));
    }
```

My Controller method :

```
    @GetMapping("/workItems/{id}")
    public WorkItem getWorkItemById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long 
    workItemId) {

    return this.workItemService.getWorkItemById(workItemId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you are not returning what the method signature declares as a return type (which is `Optional<WorkItem>`)

Just return

```
Optional.of(workitem)
```

instead of `workItem`, i.e :

```
when(workItemRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null)).thenReturn(Optional.of(workitem));
```

Comment: I tried and it shows " Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(java.util.Optional<T>) "

Comment: Could you try replacing `workItemRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null)` with just `workItemRepository.findById(1L)` ?

Comment: It compiles but then Null pointer comes out  in this line "WorkItem workItem2 = workItemsController.getWorkItemById(1L); " Should i change my service and controller method to return Optional<WorkItem> instead of WorkItem ?

Answer (score 0):

I see in comments that you tried this :

```
when(workItemRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null)).thenReturn(Optional.of(workitem));
```

It should be working.
I think the problem is comming from your 'orElse' call.

To be precise, here is the method when :

```
public static <T> OngoingStubbing<T> when(T methodCall) {
        return MOCKITO_CORE.when(methodCall);
    }
```

So i think that using 'orElse' prevent 'T' from being inferred.

And my question is why using 'orElse' ?
You're stubbing the method.

You can use 'anyString' to match any parameter.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
when(workItemRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(Optional.of(workitem).get()));
```

It woked for me

Answer (score 0):

`orElse()` method is not part of **JPA**, but it  is method of `Optional<T>` class as seen from the [doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

To make this clear let's change the following code from the service method

```
    return this.workItemRepository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new 
    ResourceNotFoundException("WorkItem", "id", id));
```

to

```
    Optional<WorkItem> workItem = this.workItemRepository.findById(id);

    return workItem.orElseThrow(() -> new 
             ResourceNotFoundException("WorkItem", "id", id));
```

So that means `orElse` method doesn't has to include in the repository method call. Since the `orElseThrow` method invoked on the Optional workItem, it creates two conditional paths. So for that it needs two test case, test case for exist work item and test case for doesn't exist work item.

**Test Case One**

```
  public void testGetWorkItemById_whenWorkItemDoesExist_returnWorkItem() {
        ...
        when(workItemRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(workItem));
        ...
        assertEquals(1L, workItem2.getId().longValue());
    }
```

**Test Case Two**

```
   @Test
    public void testGetWorkItemById_whenWorkItemDoesNotExist_returnNull() {
        ...
        when(workItemRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        ...
        assertEquals(null, workItem2);
    }
```